# Show and hide html components based on condition without using div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on Angular JS project. It has three radio buttons as follows.

```
    <div class="sys-form__field" 
     layout="row">
  <label class="sys-label sys-label--radio" flex flex-gt-xs="33">Choices</label>

  <input  type="radio"
          ng-model="booking.model.foodType"
          value="vegetarian"
          class="sys-input sys-input__radio"
          title="" />
  <md-button ng-click="booking.setRadio('foodType', 'vegetarian')">Vegetarian</md-button>
  <input  type="radio"
          ng-model="booking.model.foodType"
          value="vegan"
          class="sys-input sys-input__radio"
          title="" />
  <md-button ng-click="booking.setRadio('foodType', 'vegan')">Vegan</md-button>
  <input  type="radio"
          ng-model="booking.model.foodType"
          value="nonvegetarian"
          class="sys-input sys-input__radio"
          title="" />
  <md-button ng-click="booking.setRadio('foodType', 'nonvegetarian')">Non Vege</md-button>
</div>
```

These are the food choices and based on what user selects I want to show another radio button sets. This radio buttons html as follows

```
<div class="sys-form__field"  ng-show="booking.foodSizeChoice()"
 layout="row">

<input  type="radio"
        ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
        value="small"
        title="" > Small

<input  type="radio"
        ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
        value="medium"
        title="" > Medium           

<input  type="radio"
        ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
        value="large"
        title="" > Large
```

If user selects vegetarian , I only want to show small radio button. If user selects Non vegetarian I need to show only small and medium buttons. like wise how do I that?

At the moment I try like this

```
  this.foodTypeChoice=()=> {
 const check2 = ()=>this.model.binType == 'small';

return check2(); }
```

But it shows all the radio buttons. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this?

```
 <input  type="radio"
        ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
        value="small"
        title=""
        ng-show="booking.model.foodType == 'vegetarian'"> Small

<input  type="radio"
        ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
        value="medium"
        title="" 
        ng-show="booking.model.foodType == 'nonvegetarian'"> Medium           

<input  type="radio"
        ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
        value="large"
        title="" 
        ng-show="booking.model.foodType == 'nonvegetarian'"> Large
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work. now pizza sizes show at the first. I want to show them after button clicks. The second thing is it's not hiding. It only hide the radio button circle. I tried to add a label as well

Comment: Yes I understand, bit this is concept how you can show or hide whatever you want, just implement your condition and ude model which you need

Comment: I know the concept is ng-show , I also added that in my question :) didn't find a good answer from you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid putting functions in show/hide/if directives, it slows the application; you should use logical statements or boolean variables. You can use show/hide statements directly on inputs

```
<input
  ng-show="booking.model.foodType === 'vegetarian' || booking.model.foodType === 'nonvegetarian'"
  type="radio"
  ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
  value="small"
  title=""> Small

<input
  ng-show="booking.model.foodType === 'nonvegetarian'"
  type="radio"
  ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
  value="medium"
  title=""> Medium

<input
  type="radio"
  ng-model="booking.model.foodSize"
  value="large"
  title=""> Large
```

Apart from that you can use additional variables to store statements in them and update them whenever user clicks on buttons to change food type

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work. now pizza sizes show at the first. I want to show them after button clicks. The second thing is it's not hiding. It only hide the radio button circle. I tried to add a label as well

Comment: Hey, just create a new variable on the scope, that will be updated once user clicks on the button. Then use that variable in the div that shows whole section, add labels that will wrap inputs and put show/hide statements on them by using just created variable to check which type is picked

Comment: I created a variable as clickFoodType , initialize value as false. and in  foodTypeChoice I checked if user select small I changed clickFoodType to true. Then in ng sho of organic added that variable. Still issue is sae , all shows

Comment: u there?  @Dmitriy Uvarov

Comment: Would be better if you create a fiddle or similar small example, can you do that?